# How to match patern inside a syntax region start pattern?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, regular-expression

Python group regexp has this syntax `(?P<idGroup> ... )`, where:

- `(?P<idGroup>` is the beginning of a region.
- `...` is the content of the region.
- `)` is the end of region.

I highlight start region with matchgroup parameter of region. But I want to highlight separately `idGroup` in this start region.

Is it posible?

Comment: You could probably use two `matchgroup`s with the `contains` keyword. See the example before [`:h E849`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#E849).